# Binding v-model in dynamic table with unknown key from object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

### Binding v-model in dynamic table with unknown key from object

Hello!

I am creating a dynamic table out of an object that is dynamic. (Which means I don't know which keys will be in this object.

This works fine. Though now I want to bind the keys in the object in an input field. This does not work. It will display the correct value of the key but it is not binding it back into the data object.

```
<table
          v-if="Object.keys(this.userInfo).length > 1"
        >
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Value</th>
              <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tr v-for="(value, name) in userInfo">
            <th>{{ name }}</th>
            <th>{{value}}</th>
            <th>
              <input v-model="value" />
            </th>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

I tried to change

```
<input v-model="value" />
```

TO:

```
<input v-model="userInfo.name" />
```

Though this will just add a new key in the object called "name".

How can I bind the input field back in the object without knowing the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic key values like that:

```
    <table v-if="Object.keys(userInfo).length > 1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Value</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr v-for="key in Object.keys(userInfo)" :key="key">
        <th>{{ key }}</th>
        <th>{{ userInfo[key] }}</th>
        <th>
          <input v-model="userInfo[key]" />
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
```